# Free Code-to-Flowchart/UML tool for C# code

Tags: c#, uml, diagram, flowchart

I'm looking for a free tool similar to [Visustin](http://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html). Are there any like that that exist?

Comment: Ahh I mistook your request for one to capture the static state, not the program flow. My apologies. I've removed my less than useful earlier answer.

Comment: have you found any? im looking for the same

Answer (score 1):

Not free but our tool, Code Rocket can generate flowcharts from C# code. You can try it out free at [www.rapidqualitysystems.com](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com)

I hope this is helpful for anyone else that comes across this post.

Alan

Comment: I attempted to install the trial version on VS2017 professional and I got a message stating it was not compatible and could render my install unstable?  As I don't have time to clean up if this corrupts my development environment, I may pass, but it looks promising.

Comment: I have replied to your email but the warning can be safely ignored. It is due to the way that we build the plugin to be compatible with VS2010 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, it has a "[Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx)" which can generate code from UML diagrams and diagrams from code. Here is an excerpt from the features page of Feature Pack 2:

Code visualization and modeling features (requires Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate):

- Use the Generate Code command to generate skeleton code from elements on UML class diagrams. You can use the default transformations, or you can write custom transformations to translate UML types into code.
- Create UML class diagrams from existing code.
- Import elements from UML sequence diagrams, class diagrams, and use case diagrams as XMI 2.1 files that are exported from other modeling tools.